# MOSFETs Gate Driver: Current drawn from the Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, mosfet-driver

I'm going to use a [**L6491 High voltage high and low-side 4 A gate driver**](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6491.pdf)  to drive a half bridge made from two IPW65R019C7.
I'm going to use a +15V to supply the L6491 MOSFET Driver.

How can I have an idea about the current drawn by the L6491 from the +15 power supply?

I don't know exacly which is the parameter on the datasheet which gives me this infomation. Is it the supply current Is, Sourcing Output Current ISrc or the Sinking Output Current ISNK?

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Data sheet link?

Comment: Sorry, the pictures is about another Driver. The correct link is https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6491.pdf

Comment: The L6491 gives some specific IC operating currents - which are NOT the same as drive currents. drive currents are intermittent and occur during gate transitions (high or low) in order to charge/discharge the FET gate capacitance(s). IC current is quiescent current plus the energy to supply drive currents.  Idrive  = Energy drive / Vdrive > 2 x Energy_gate_capacitance x Drive_frequency (roughly :-) )

Answer (score 1):

The supply current when not driving MOSFET gates will be negligible compared to when the MOSFETs are attached. That is why it doesn't appear to be specified in the data sheet. So, if you want a realistic value for current calculate the average current waveform into the gate source capacitance and bear in mind that each MOSFET gets charged and discharged every switching cycle.

As an example, if the gate-source capacitance is 2 nF and the driving voltage is 15 volts then an energy of 2 nF * 225 / 2 joules is required for each MOSFET each cycle. That's a total MOSFET gate energy of 450 nJ and, if this is operating at 100 kHz, that's an average power of 45 mW. Given that the power taken from the supply is going to be more than double this value you can estimate 100 mW just to drive the gates.

From a 15 volt supply that is about 7 mA.

Add-on a few extra mA for internal consumption and you are in the 10 mA region. Clearly if the MOSFET gates are higher capacitance (can be 10 nF or more), the overall consumption will rise towards 40 mA.

Comment: Andy's possibly obscure "2 nF * 225 / 2 joules" = 0.5 x C x V^2 x 2

Comment: Input capacitance Ciss is a differential parameter varying a lot with voltages applied. Qg or better Qtot are the parametes to be used instead.